# Cannot stream files in subfolders with wildcards in pySpark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, scala-spark

This code works only if I make `directory="s3://bucket/folder/2022/10/18/4/*"`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)

directory = "s3://bucket/folder/*/*/*/*/*"
stream_data = ssc.textFileStream(directory)

def readMyStream(rdd):
  if not rdd.isEmpty():
    df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(rdd)
    print('Started the Process')
    print('Selection of Columns')
    df = df.select("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5")
    df.show()
    
stream_data.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: readMyStream(rdd)) 

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

In the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) it says it supports POSIX glob pattern. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried directory = "s3://bucket/folder/" , If yes then what issue are you getting

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the final `*` should not be there. In the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) it says "it is a pattern of directories, not of files in directories". I didnt understand it the first time I read it.

`A POSIX glob pattern can be supplied, such as "hdfs://namenode:8040/logs/2017/*". Here, the DStream will consist of all files in the directories matching the pattern. That is: it is a pattern of directories, not of files in directories.`

`directory = "s3://bucket/folder/*/*/*/*/*"` should be  directory = `"s3://bucket/folder/*/*/*/*/"`